# Finding the biggest element in a list of lists

Tags: python, nested-lists

I'm catching up with Python3 so I hope I can get some slack :P
I have a list of lists, say:

```
results=[[1, 5000],
 [2, 5000],
 [3, 6666],
 [4, 6250],
 [5, 6000],
 [6, 5833],
 [7, 5714],
 [8, 6250],
 [9, 6111]]
```

And I would like to get the entry which has the biggest second value (in this case, the pair `[3, 6666]`).

Could I have some quick reference on how to get it?

Thanks!

Comment: This community isn't a "do all the work for you" service, it's more to help you get unstuck from a specific problem with code. You can't show zero effort and expect a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach using [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

```py
import operator
 
>>> max(results, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
[3, 6666]
>>>
```